# Weird ReSharper issue with action lists that don't work

Tags: resharper, actionlist

So we had a power outage at work the other day and ever since then [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) and Visual Studio just aren't playing nicely. The issue occurs when I try to click on one of the light bulb action lists, they just disappear. I also noticed that when I compile and there is an error, the error list acts like it's trying to open, but it doesn't. I have un-installed and re-installed ReSharper and run a repair on Visual Studio. How can I fix this?

You can see an example of what I mean here:
http://rapidshare.com/files/197237456/resharper.avi

Comment: Nice video.  What software did you use to put that together?

Comment: Camtasia will produce such videos: http://www.techsmith.com/

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem with Resharper 4.5.2

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, including having the Visual Studio database edition installed, and solved it by resetting the Visual Studio settings.

From the Visual Studio command prompt (for instance, menu *Start* -> *Programs* -> *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008* -> *Visual Studio Tools* -> *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt*) do:

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

Note: you might need to run the command prompt as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the Visual Studio Database Edition installed and apparently it causes issues with ReSharper. I un-installed it and the problem went away.

Comment: You should mark it this as the answer if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the context actions menu via the shortcut key?  On my install (IntelliJ/R#2 key bindings) the shortcut is `ALT+ENTER`.

If you do try another reinstall, you might like to revert to default factory settings by moving the settings file (`My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`) and seeing if it's a config thing.

Also, you haven't stated what version of R# you're using.  I see that you're using auto properties so that must be VS2008.  Are you using the [nightly builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds) for 4.5?

Failing all of this, your best bet would be to file a bug report with [JetBrains's issue tracker, Jira](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP).

Good luck with this one.  I hate being without ReSharper!

Comment: Thanks for replying.  No, I can't access them via alt+enter either, they just disappear.  I'm currently using 4.1.  I sent support an email and haven't heard back in days.

Comment: Create an issue on their Jira site.  I've found that method fairly good for having issues resolved.  You might also try the 4.5 builds.  They're working well for me.